# internal fake links shows in google search results

Tags: wordpress, spam, malware-detection, antimalware

I recently had a strange problem on my site. This is a problem with urls that have not any relation my content (see screenshot with fake links in google search results). Fortunately these links are no external spam links.

So I decided to do the following steps:

I've reviewed my site with a security checker, such as sucuri, unmasking, and all of these sites announced that my site is completely clean.
I deleted the old WordPress files (except wp-config & wp content folder) and replaced them with fresh and clean files.
1.I replaced the entire theme system files (php, js, etc.) with new and fresh files.

2.I changed all the passwords and worpress salts with using itheme security plugin, removed .htaccess file and let wordpress create a new one.

3.I removed the unrelated links using google webmasters.

4.I also removed suspicious plugins and restored the full version of my site's backup two weeks ago.

Unfortunately until today the links are not gone. All urls share the same word "marblehead". Like the following URL:

omranf1.com/conkers/marblehead/15244_17630.asp/page/2/

The interesting thing is that in the description section of search results of each of these URLs, abstract part (or meta tag description) of content of my site is displayed.

Has anyone come up with a solution to this problem? I'm really confused how to get rid of this problem!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Could you clearify the very last part of the question: "The interesting thing is that in the description section of search results of each of these URLs, abstract part (or meta tag description) of content of my site is displayed." Its very hard to understand...

Comment: Hi Axel
Thank you for your attention and response.
Yes, Sure. To better understand what I mean, I will send a screenshot of Google results page and explain on it.
(to see screenshot click on following link:
https://ibb.co/cEmzEF
)

Comment: Ah ok - so the desciption of the fake links his hijacked from descriptions of actual links...

Comment: yes. have you any suggestion?

Comment: Not really. In my experience it can last up to 2-6 weeks when you ask google to remove urls via webmastertools; maybe double check if they are actually marked to remove in your webmastertools... But with the "marblehead"-problem - I don't have a clue. To troubleshoot things like that one should have access to all related ressources including access to the server. Maybe you have luck and somebody knows better! I suggest to approve the edit which I already made to your post and make your question sharper/clearer and the whole post better understandable to increase chances to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks Axel.
I've been changed my question with that you suggested.
hope find a solution for my problem.